# Issues with Android Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

Look at this...

[image]

This is the main screen of the android app I'm developing. When user touches first EditText, the system keyboard shows like this:

[image]

But when user touches second EditText, the keyboard shows like this:

[image]

Without that black bar on top of it... Does anyone knows why is this? I'm working with a Samsung Galaxy Nexus... Besides... I noted that the keyboard is displayed on top of GUI... but in another screen of my app the keboard makes the GUI to roll up, like this:

[image]

In this last image, on top of the three buttons is a ScrollView, is this the reason for the keyboard make this effect?

Can anybody help me here? I'm stuck!
Thanks!

Comment: If the second EditText is defined as EditText for password, the black bar doesn't show, because there are no suggestions on password EditTexts. On the first one there is, because its not secret or anything (the username).

Comment: Looks like the keyboard tries to align just under the EditText and in your top EditText the keyboard is spacing out with black

Comment: You can influence how your activty reacts to soft keyboard being shown, see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft